# Galois group of $X^n-t$ over $\mathbb{C}(t)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, galois-theory, solution-verification

I would just like to check my reasoning:

The polynomial $f(X)=X^n-t \in \mathbb{C}(t)[X]$ is irreducible as it is Eisenstein at the prime $t$ in $\mathbb{C}[t]$ and $\mathbb{C}(\sqrt[n]{t})$ is a splitting field for $f$ over $\mathbb{C}(t)$ as the latter contains all (in particular, the $n$th) roots of unity. It follows that there is an isomorphism of groups
$$\theta:\textrm{Gal}(f/\mathbb{C}(t))\longrightarrow \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$$
defined by $\sigma(\sqrt[n]{t})=\zeta_n^{\theta(\sigma)}\sqrt[n]{t}.$

Is this correct?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Yes, this is correct.

Comment: To amplify @MooS’s comment, I’ll say that any time the $n$-th roots of unity are in the base field, adjoining an $n$-th root of an alement to the base will lead to a cyclic Galois group.

Comment: Just curious, what would the galois group be over $\mathbb{R}(t)$? Also, is this reasoning affected by whether or not $t$ is transcendental over $\mathbb{C}$?